# how to add Captcha to my custom form in Wordpress without plugin?

Tags: wordpress, captcha

Is there any way to add captcha into my custom form in WordPress, i have gone through some plugins but it allows only to add Captcha in login, comment forms etc..

i have used Google reCaptcha where i have used this script

```
<script type="text/javascript"
       src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key">
    </script>
    <noscript>
       <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=your_public_key"
           height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
       <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
       </textarea>
       <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
           value="manual_challenge">
    </noscript>
```

it's working fine on contact page but if i click on submit it's not validated what code should i place in contact page so, that it works with validation.

Comment: So you put your code in that page and it doesn't show?

Comment: yes its not working on dashboard->pages->contact page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be checking for validation of the answer and not just displaying the block with the captcha challenge. 
https://web.archive.org/web/20121108134349/https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php

```
  <?php
 require_once('recaptchalib.php');
 $privatekey = "your_private_key";
 $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
   die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
     "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} else {
      // Your code here to handle a successful verification
}
?>
```